# Display list of images in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm having trouble displaying a list of images in JSP. I have a list of images which is stored in the project director and the list of images is pass to the JSP file from the servlet but it won't display. I need some assistance with my jsp tag.

In the JSP file, I have

```
<c:forEach var="img" items="${imgUrlList}">
    <img src="<c:url value="${img}"/>"/>

</c:forEach>
```

//servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List imgUrlList = new ArrayList();

        File imageDir = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/images"));
        File[] files = imageDir.listFiles();

            if (files!= null) {

                for (File imageFile : files) {
                    String imageFileName = imageFile.getName();
                    imgUrlList.add(imageFileName);
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("directory is empty");
            }

        req.setAttribute("imgUrlList", imgUrlList);
        System.out.println(imgUrlList.toString());

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test/test.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
```

Comment: Let's say your `images` resource folder contains a `foo.gif` file, which means you add ``C:\path\to\webapp\images\foo.gif`` to the list and therefore generate something like `<img src="C:\path\to\webapp\images\foo.gif"/>`, but the problem is that that file exists on the *server*, not on the *client* computer, so it doesn't work. You need to generate a URL that will be picked up by the webapp, i.e. `<img src="/CONTEXT/images/foo.gif"/>`

Comment: I've tried  without any luck. <c:forEach var="img" items="${imgUrlList}">
    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}${img}"/>

</c:forEach>

Comment: Try doing a "View Source" in the browser, so you can see the result of the JSP. Then you might better understand the *real* problem, i.e. the fact that the file paths are **fully qualified**.

Comment: You need to create images folder within WebContent folder.

Answer (score 1):

The image 'src' attribute is relative to the context root of your web application. Images are stored outside of WEB-INF folder. Create 'images' folder to the "WebContent" folder of your project.

WEB-INF is usually used for resources which are used by container like jsps and other resources are usually in folders relative to the WebContent folder.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by appending my jsp.

```html
<c:forEach var="img" items="${imgUrlList}">

    <img src="images/${request.contextPath}${img}"/>

</c:forEach>
```